# Variance of product of two random variables ($f(X, Y) = XY$)

Tags: random-variables, variance

I want to compute the variance of $f(X, Y) = XY$, where $X$ and $Y$ are randomly independent.

If I use the definition for the variance $Var[X] = E[(X-E[X])^2]$ and replace $X$ by $f(X,Y)$ I end up with the following expression

$$Var[XY] = Var[X]Var[Y] + Var[X]E[Y]^2 + Var[Y]E[X]^2$$

I have found this result also on Wikipedia: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_random_variables)

However, I also found [this](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/%7Eucfbpve/geotopes/indexch10.html) approach, where the resulting formula is

$$Var[XY] = 2E[X]E[Y]COV[X,Y]+ Var[X]E[Y]^2 + Var[Y]E[X]^2$$

where the first term is zero since $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

I would like to know which approach is correct for independent random variables? Or are they actually the same and I miss something?

Comment: What is the problem ? You get the same formula in both cases.

Comment: @ArnaudMégret Can you explain why. I don't see that. If $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables, the second expression is $Var[XY] = Var[X]E[Y]^2 + Var[Y]E[X]^2$ while  the first on is  $Var[XY] = Var[X]Var[Y] + Var[X]E[Y]^2 + Var[Y]E[X]^2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to independence of $X$ and $Y$ and of $X^2$ and $Y^2$ we have

\begin{align}
{\rm Var}[XY]&=E[X^2Y^2]-E[XY]^2=E[X^2]\,E[Y^2]-E[X]^2\,E[Y]^2\\
&={\rm Var}[X]\,{\rm Var}[Y]+E[X^2]\,E[Y]^2+E[X]^2\,E[Y^2]-2E[X]^2E[Y]^2\\
\tag{1}
&={\rm Var}[X]\,{\rm Var}[Y]+{\rm Var}[X]\,E[Y]^2+{\rm Var}[Y]\,E[X]^2\,.
\end{align}
This is your first formula.

As far as I can tell the authors of that link that leads to the second formula are making a number of silent but crucial assumptions:

First, they assume that $X_i-\overline{X}$ and $Y_i-\overline{Y}$ are small so that approximately
$$\tag{2}
X_iY_i-\overline{XY}\approx(X_i-\overline{X})\overline{Y}+(Y_i-\overline{Y})\overline{X}\,
$$
holds.
If we knew $\overline{XY}=\overline{X}\,\overline{Y}$ (which is not necessarly true)  formula (2) (which is their (10.7) in a cleaner notation) could be viewed as a Taylor expansion to first order. The authors write (2) as an equation and stay silent about the assumptions leading to it. By squaring (2) and summing up they obtain
$$\tag{10.13*}
\sigma_{XY}^2\approx \sigma_X^2\overline{Y}^2+\sigma_Y^2\overline{X}^2+2\,{\rm Cov}[X,Y]\overline{X}\,\overline{Y}\,.
$$
This is in my opinion an cleaner notation of their (10.13).

The whole story can probably be reconciled as follows: If $X$ and $Y$ are independent  then $\overline{XY}=\overline{X}\,\overline{Y}$ holds and (10.13*) becomes
$$\tag{3}
\sigma_{XY}^2\approx \sigma_X^2\overline{Y}^2+\sigma_Y^2\overline{X}^2\,.
$$
The assumption that $X_i-\overline{X}$ and $Y_i-\overline{Y}$ are small is not far from assuming ${\rm Var}[X]{\rm Var}[Y]$ being very small. Hence your first equation (1) approximately says the same as (3).

BTW, the exact version of (2) is obviously
$$
\tag{4}
X_iY_i-\overline{X}\,\overline{Y}=(X_i-\overline{X})\overline{Y}+(Y_i-\overline{Y})\overline{X}+(X_i-\overline{X})(Y_i-\overline{Y})\,.
$$
and this holds without the assumpton that $X_i-\overline{X}$ and $Y_i-\overline{Y}$ are small. Not sure though if a useful equation for $\sigma^2_{XY}$ can be derived from this.

Comment: I followed Equation (10.13) of the second link with $a=1$.

Comment: @Samuel : see my edit.